# NetSuite query - select transactions with messages rows

Tags: transactions, netsuite, message, suiteql

I want to select Transaction with/without associated messages rows.

The purpose is to define is Email sent from transaction.
That means I need to fetch all transactions regardless of whether they have related messages.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyiyP.png)

Comment: Can you supply some more detail about what you are trying to accomplish? Do you want to use a saved search? What was the point of the screen shot of the built-in messages sublist?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you wanted to do this via SuiteQL Queries. If so, here's how:

To get Transactions with Messages:

```
SELECT M.transaction.*, T.*
FROM Message as M, transaction as T
WHERE M.transaction IS NOT NULL 
AND M.transaction = T.id
```

To get Transactions without Messages:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM transaction as T
WHERE T.id NOT IN (
SELECT M.transaction 
FROM Message as M
WHERE M.transaction IS NOT NULL 
) M.transaction IS NOT NULL
```